# Debian vServer: Cannot connect to VPN with multiple devices in same network

Tags: server, debian, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I set up a VPN on my virtual Server using openswan, xl2tpd and ppp (see this tutorial: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_with_Ubuntu_14.04.html).
So I am talking about a L2TP/IPSec VPN with a PSK.

The problem I have:
I can connect a smartphone with the VPN using the on-board API.
But after that I cannot connect any more devices to the VPN using a device from the same network (others or cell-networks are working).
For me that means NAT-support isn't enabled but as shown in the tutorial I set the nat_traversal-value in /etc/ipsec.conf to "yes".

Actually, if I connect a windows-computer first, I CAN connect both the computer and one more other device (smartphone), but I am NOT able to connect another device.

I am sure the problem isn't:
 - the phone: Sometimes I can connect, sometimes not, as shown above. No installations block anything.
 - the router: A connection to the VPN is not impossible.
 - the server itself: A connection to the VPN is not impossible.

I see the problem in the configs but I have no clue where to look for these settings.
If someone knows what to do I appreciate every answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem in the config files. 
For anyone who has the same problem, add the values to the /etc/ipsec.conf as shown below:

```
version 2.0

config setup
    oe=off
    listen=%IP_ADDRESS%

conn L2TP-PSK-NAT
    rightsubnet=vhost:%priv
    also=L2TP-PSK-noNAT

conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
    rekey=yes
```

It should work after that c: